# AJAX и CORS, составление кроссдоменного запроса

Tags: ajax, php, javascript, cors

Имеется функция создания ajax запроса:

```
$(".call_number").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://%my_site%/api/%my_script%.php",
  data: $(this).attr(\'href\'),
  success: function(msg){
  }
 });
});
```

При попытке вызова получаю ошибку:

> Сhrome " XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> %мой запрос%. No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
> is present on the requested resource.
> Origin %домен запроса% is therefore
> not allowed access." Mozilla "Запрос
> из постороннего источника
> заблокирован: Политика одного
> источника запрещает чтение удаленного
> ресурса на %мой запрос%. Это может
> быть исправлено путем перемещения
> ресурса в тот же домен или включением
> CORS."

Далее нашел в https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing, что для исправления этой ошибки нужно добавить в код php скрипта:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
```

Добавил. Далее нашел в http://habrahabr.ru/post/219895/, что нужно вставить в ajax:

```
xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
```

Но так и не понял, в какое место это нужно воткнуть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно составить функцию кроссдоменного запроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставка `credentialed`-флага запроса, crossDomain-аттрибут.
Спешу заметить, что `withCredentials` передают в запросе данные аутентификации и сессии, и скорее всего это не то, что Вам нужно.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://%my_site%/api/%my_script%.php",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: $(this).attr('href'),
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function(out) {
    console.log(out);
  }
});
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо :)