# jquery get ajax json error -> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Я пытаюсь получить информацию в формате json, но получаю следующую ошибку ->  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "get",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("error" + error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что серверный скрипт отдает невалидную JSON структуру. Попробуйте вручную получить содержимое

```
http://football-api.com/api/Action=today&APIKey=secrettoken&comp_id=1204
```

и проверить с помощью какого-нибудь JSON валидатора (например http://jsonlint.com/).

**UPD:**

Не сразу заметил, но вы пытаетесь работать с API используя JSONP. Если вам действительно нужен этот протокол (а это скорее всего так, поскольку запросы кросс-доменные), то вам следует проверять ответ по URL:

```
http://football-api.com/api/Action=today&APIKey=secrettoken&comp_id=1204&callback=test
```

Правильный ответ от сервера должен содержать что-то вроде:

```
test({/* Объект с данными */})
```

Если это не так, и ответ имеет вид

```
{/* Объект с данными */}
```

то ваш API не умеет работать с JSONP запросами и вам нужно смотреть в сторону [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). На ru.SO уже поднимался вопрос про кросс-доменные AJAX запросы(см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/392433/ajax-%D0%B8-cors-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)).

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужен именно JSON**P** а не просто JSON?

Comment: Отлично. А `football-api.com` вообще поддерживает JSONP? Проверить очень легко: добавьте к вашему URL строку `&callback=test` и откройте этот URL в браузере. Если JSON объект не будет обернут в `callback(...)` то API, с которым вы пытаетесь работать не поддерживает JSONP.

Comment: я получил тоже самое что и без &callback=test

Comment: Поздравляю, ваш API не умеет работать с JSONP. Копайте в сторону [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: Посмотрите вот [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/392433/ajax-%D0%B8-cors-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)